# Adding a new role type to Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, roles, user-management

Is there a way to add new roles to reporting services?

I'm working on a clients project and it requires a custom role in Reporting Services. I can't find any page in my http://localhost/reports that will allow me to configure a new role. I can only assign users and groups to existing roles.

I looked in the [ReportServer].[dbo].[Roles] table of my database and found the current roles but I'm not sure what some of the columns do/mean so I don't want to just go adding a new record.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can certainly create new roles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/role-definitions-create-delete-or-modify?view=sql-server-2017

This is done through a seldom-used feature of SSRS: you connect to SSRS through the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) by specifying a server type of "Reporting Services"

Comment: is there any way of adding multiple roles in one go using a script, say I have a list of 50 roles which all will be able to do the same tasks, but need to have different names, is this possible?